# How to consolidate roles and templates to the same playbook

Tags: ansible

I need to use a provisioning tool called vcommander
looks like this tool supports running ansible locally on the provisioned host
only, and you need to provide him only the playbook to run.

I already have working ansible roles which includes tasks and templates for examples the ntp role looks toughtly like below:

`ls -1 roles/ntp/`

```
defaults
LICENSE
meta
README.md
tasks
templates
```

the main task looks something like this:

`cat roles/ntp/tasks/main.yml`

```
---

- name: "Configure ntp.conf"
  template:
    src: "ntp.conf.j2"
    dest: "/etc/ntp.conf"
    mode: "0644"
    become: True

- name: Updating time zone
  shell: tzdata-update

- name: Ensure NTP-related packages are installed.
  package:
  name: ntp
 state: present

- name: Ensure NTP is running and enabled as configured.
  service:
  name:  ntpd
 state: started
enabled: yes
```

and the template looks like this:

`cat roles/ntp/templates/ntp.conf.j2`

```
{{ ansible_managed }}

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict -6 ::1

server 127.127.1.0
fudge   127.127.1.0 stratum 10

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
keys /etc/ntp/keys
```

Is there a way to include the main.yml and the ntp.conf.j2 (template) 
and other files included in the roles into one yml file?
Please provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for a playbook that applies your ntp role to `localhost`?

It would look like this:

`cat playbook.yml`

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - ntp
```

See docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles

Comment: The question was how to include the task and the template to the same yml file?

Comment: So you want to do way with the role, and literally have only a *single file*?